# Secure Java application using Keycloak saml

Tags: java, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to secure my java application using Keycloak security for the I have added all the kecycloak saml dependency. In web.xml I have added below config:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>APP</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.saml.servlet.SamlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>APP</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also added keycloal-saml.xml file in WEB-INF folder as below:

```
<keycloak-saml-adapter>
<SP entityID="http://localhost:9222/APP/"
    sslPolicy="EXTERNAL"
    logoutPage="logout">
    <Keys>
        <Key signing="true">
            <PrivateKeyPem>
                <!-- Private Key -->
            </PrivateKeyPem>
            <CertificatePem>
              <!-- Certi Key -->
            </CertificatePem>
        </Key>
    </Keys>
    <IDP entityID="idp"
         signatureAlgorithm="RSA_SHA256"
         signatureCanonicalizationMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
         metadataUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml/descriptor">
        <SingleSignOnService signRequest="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             validateAssertionSignature="false"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             bindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"/>
        <SingleLogoutService signRequest="true"
                             signResponse="true"
                             validateRequestSignature="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             responseBinding="POST"
                             postBindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"
                             redirectBindingUrl="http://localhost:8280/realms/IDP_REALM/protocol/saml"/>
         <Keys>
            <Key signing="true">
                <KeyStore resource="/WEB-INF/keystore.jks" password="store123">
                    <Certificate alias="Test"/>
                </KeyStore>
            </Key>
        </Keys>
    </IDP>
</SP>
```

and also added keycloak.jsk file and my application is getting up properly but the when I try to access my application it is redirecting to keycloak to validate that is right but keycloak is showing below error:

[image]

Also keycloak config is as follow:
[image]
Could you please help what am I missing in configuration so that it should show proper keycloak login page?

And keycloak shows error:

```
type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=IDP_REALM, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.22.0.1, error=client_not_found, reason=Cannot_match_source_hash
```